# How to implement big int or big decimal as a datatype in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow has no big integer or big decimal as a dtype. And it says that tf.strings can represent any kind of bytes array. Can I implement big data type using tf.strings? Or is there any other way?

Comment: I imagine it would be technically possible to implement big integer or big decimal operations in TensorFlow using `tf.string`, but it would be really complicated and most likely very slow (more or less similar to NumPy). Currently there is no support for these types in TensorFlow, and I don't think it is on the roadmap. As for "any other way", I suppose you could use `tf.py_func` and operate with Python integers (which are arbitrarily large) or the `decimal` module.

Comment: @jdehesa  
I check the document, the example is `y = tf.py_func(my_func, [input], tf.float32)` , how to deal with the tf.float32 while actually I want to use `decimal` module? Thanks